# Develop a EA-BaseliningMerge workflow in C#

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I want to develop a workflow to merge a baseline in EA as described via GUI:

1. Right click on a package and select "Package Control" > "Package
   Baseline" (STRG + ALT + B)
2. Click "Compare Model To File"
3. Select a XMI file
4. After comparing...
5. Select package (in "Model elements" and not in the "Project browser") > right-click -> "Merge from Baseline (with options)"

I think that I have to use the following methods (like described in [EA Class API](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.0/automation/project_2.html)) but I have no idea how to use these:

```
EA.App eaApp = new EA.App();
EA.Repository repository = null;
if (eaApp.Repository.OpenFile2(/*FileOrDB*/"...", /*User*/"...",/*PWD*/"...")){
    repository = eaApp.Repository;
    repository.GetProjectInterface().DoBaselineCompare(...);
    repository.GetProjectInterface().DoBaselineMerge(...);
}
```

Can someone post me an example to execute these steps in C#?

Comment: Are you developing an Add-In for integration into EA's GUI or a stand-alone application? It has a bearing on how to get hold of the Repository in the first step.

Comment: I am developing a batch job. In this case a stand-alone application.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation of both DoBaseLine... methods it seems that you can only use these with baselines that are actually stored in the (or another) model.
There is nothing in the API that allows you to compare with an xmi file.

But there is a workaround. You can import the xmi file into another model, create a baseline for it there using `ProjectInterface.CreateBaseline` or `ProjectInterface.CreateBaselineEx`.

Once you have this baseline you can compare it with the package in your model and merge it.